# Why should I search in MongoDB for user in session case using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, express-session

I am using express-session and mongoose.
When the user authenticates, I put his data in the session:

```
req.session.user = candidate
req.session.isAuthenticated = true
req.session.save()
```

I've created middleware for checking if req.session.user exists and putting it in the request:

```
if (!req.session.user) {
   return next()
}
req.user = await User.findById(req.session.user._id)
next()
```

If I use instead of *req.user = await User.findById(req.session.user._id)* just this: **req.user = req.session.user**
It will not allow me to access userSchema methods as if in that case req.user isn't a Schema Type Object.

Can you please explain, how and why it works like this?
Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `express-session` package documentation mentions this:

> To store or access session data, simply use the request property
> req.session, which is (generally) serialized as JSON by the store.

So for the purpose of storage, the object referenced at `req.session` is actually serialized - ie turned into a string representation - to the session store on save, and later deserialized from the session store when an request comes in.

As part of this serialization process, some information is lost - including object methods and maybe more importantly the actual type of the object. As a result, when the object is restored from the serialized version, what you're getting is basically a generic object with only non-function properties.

Note this process is recursive, so what applies to `req.session` applies to any nested object.

You can simulate this with the JSON serializer that is part of the standard library:

```
class Session {
    randomMethod() { }
}

var session = new Session()
session.someData = "Some data"

var serialized = JSON.stringify(session)
var restored = JSON.parse(serialized)

console.log(session instanceof Session)     // true
console.log(restored instanceof Session)    // false
console.log("randomMethod" in session)      // true
console.log("randomMethod" in restored)     // false
console.log(session.someData)               // "Some data"
console.log(restored.someData)              // "Some data"
```